# How to rewrite tslint rule for particular file?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I prefer quotemark: [true, "single"], but for lib.core.es6.d.ts I need use "double".

I tried use comments like eslint:

```
/*tslint qoutemark: [true, "double"]*/
```

but it doesn't work.

Maybe I can ignore some files using tslint.json?

Comment: It's probably best to not bother running tslint on files you don't maintain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently you cannot change the options for a rule - you can only enable/disable a rule for specific lines of code.

For example, say you had the `object-literal-sort-keys` rule enabled in your `tslint.json` file. You could then do something like this to disable it for a portion of a file and then renable it for the rest of the file:

```
/* tslint:disable:object-literal-sort-keys */
const range = {
   min: 5,
   middle: 10,    // TSLint will *not* warn about unsorted keys here
   max: 20
};
/* tslint:enable:object-literal-sort-keys */
```

See [the TSLint website](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... Comment like this work:

```
/* tslint:disable:variable-name quotemark:[true, "double"] */
```

issue solved.